# How to avoid casting of a Parent's field in subclasses

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

My `Parent` class is like this:

```
public abstract class Parent{

  protected HashMap<String, Foo> field;
  public abstract void method1();
}
```

Now, the two children of `Parent` class need to iterate through the `HashMap` to do something. The first child needs the `Foo` class, so there's no problem. The second child, though, has `method1()` implemented like this:

```
@Override
public void method1(){
  for(Foo i : this.field.values(){
    ((Bar) i).specificMethod();
    /* other code */
  }
}
```

with `Bar` that extends `Foo`, of course. As you can see, a cast is mandatory to use the specific method of the `Bar` class. Can this be avoided is some way? I know I could use Generics in `Parent` class like this:

```
public abstract class Parent<T extends Foo>{

  protected HashMap<String, T> field;
  /* etc. */
}
```

but I don't know if this is considered bad behavior.

Comment: Declare the map as `Map<String, Bar>` ?, if it contains `Bar`s any ways.

Comment: Your generic approach, `class Parent<T extends Foo>`, is fine. There’s another option in prashant’s answer. I’d immediately prefer the generics, but you can best weigh the pros and cons yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child class already has an intimate knowledge of the contents of the map. Casting, as you mentioned, is a ugly and dodgy approach. Moving this declaration to the generic specification of the class makes it much more obvious, and would probably be the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your foo class should have a method which bar will override.....so in all cases you will call

`i.execute()`

where execute is a method in foo which will be override by subclasses....doing this would remove the need to explicitly cast the object to the sub class type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not the case. `Bar`'s method should not be present in Foo class. I'll keep your suggestion for the future, if I understood your answer correctly.